# Concatenate files using a specific order based on another file

Tags: bash, io-redirection, file-management

I would like to concatenate multiple files following a specific order from an other file.

I have multiple files called `freq_<something>` that I want to concatenate.
The "something" are listed in another file called "list".

So here is my list:

```
$ cat list
003137F
002980F
002993F
```

I want to do:

```
cat freq_003137F freq_002980F freq_002993F > freq_all
```

But my list contains hundreds of values so I can't really do that!

What is a way to automate it? I thought I could append a file with a `while read line` but it fails...

Thanks!

M

Comment: Usually a ?`while read`-type loop should be fine here. Care to add your code so we might take a look?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with a `while`, why not? This should work:

```bsh
while read suffix; do cat freq_"${suffix}"; done < list > freq_all; done
```

Alternatively, you can generate the command with `printf` and run it manually:

```bsh
$ echo "cat $(printf 'freq_%s ' $(cat list)) > freq_out"
cat freq_003137F freq_002980F freq_002993F > freq_out
```

Or simply execute it directly:

```
cat $(printf 'freq_%s ' $(cat list)) > freq_out
```

Comment: The latter two might fail with very big lists, though. You might want to mention that limitation.

Comment: @FelixJN when would they fail? There is no globbing here, so we shouldn't hit the MAX_ARGS and I tested with a file with 100000000 lines (`cat $(printf 'freq_%s ' $(cat aa))>f 2>/dev/null`).

Comment: Yes, I thought about the MAX_ARGS limit. I am baffled it would not take effect here.

Comment: It's not globbing per-se that's relevant, it's a kernel-defined limit on how big an `argv[]` array you can pass through an `execve()` system call (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).  You're running `cat` with those args, not a shell built-in, so it can't hide this.  Agreed with @FelixJN; if you still have that test setup, you could run `strace -o cat.tr  cat $(printf ...)` to see if it's actually getting invoked with that many args.  Note that the actual limit on Linux is a few MiB, *much* higher than the guaranteed minimum from a .h file.

Comment: Fun fact: you can optimize away the `cat list` by using `$( <list)` to have bash just read the file itself, like an implicit cat in a command substitution with a redirect but not command.

Answer (score 11):

Use `xargs`

```
xargs -i cat freq_'{}' < list > freq_all
```

Comment: Use uppercase `-I` instead, as `-i` option is deprecated; so `xargs -I{} cat freq_'{}' < list`

Comment: Unfortunately this stops xargs from putting more than 1 arg on each `cat` command line, so there's a fork/exec of cat for each file, not just cat going through its arg list doing open/read.  `sed 's/^/freq_/'  list | xargs -d'\n' cat` would be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use xargs, generally you want to take advantage of its ability to put more than 1 arg on the command line of a single process.  (Running one `cat` that loops over its args is more efficient than running a separate `cat` process for each file, given process startup overhead).

`xargs '-I{}'  cat freq_'{}'` unfortunately implies `-x` `-L 1`, and refuses to allow overriding it back to doing multiple args per command.

Instead, we can use `sed` to do the substitution.  This could be good if you have a *very* large list, which might be too large for the bash command-substitution with printf in @terdon's answer.  xargs knows to batch args into chunks of up to 128kiB of text (by default).

```
sed 's/^/freq_/' list | xargs -d'\n' cat   > freq_out
```

`s/^/foo/` prepends stuff to the start of a line.  The pattern matches 0 width at the start of each line.